# How to add add key to react-select multi?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

How can I add key element to react-select with ismulti, so when I select multiple options it doesn't give me this error "Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `[object Object]`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version."

here is my code:

```
         let options = data.map( (item,index) => (
             { index: item.name, value: item, label: item.name })
             );
   
      setOptions(options);
```

in the return part here is how I'm setting the react-select

```
 <Select 
        
            value={selectedOptions || ''}       
            className="select-name"
            isMulti
            name="selectedOption"
            onChange={handleChange}
            isClearable             
            options={Options}              
        />
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [solution](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2844#issuecomment-584924464) suggested on the discussion about the same issue on github.

Essentially you would add a `toString` method to the object used as the value in your options. This allows you to control the format of the key (which otherwise is generated by casting the `value` property to a string, hence the duplicated `[object Object]` keys.

In your case it might look something like this:

```
const options = data.map((item, index) => ({
  index: item.name,
  value: {
    ...item,
    toString: () => item.id // assumes item has a unique id property
  },
  label: item.name
}));

setOptions(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getOptionValue` prop from the Select component like so:

```
getOptionValue={({ value }) => value.name}
```